# Handle Unicode characters with Python regexes

Tags: python, regex, unicode, utf-8

I'm writing a simple application where I want to replace certain words with other words. I'm running into problems with words that use single quotes such as `aren't`, `ain't`, `isn't`.

I have a text file with the following

```
aren’t=ain’t
hello=hey
```

I parse the text file and create a dictionary out of it

```
u'aren\u2019t' = u'ain\u2019t'
u'hello' = u'hey'
```

Then I try to replace all the characters in a given text

```
text = u"aren't"

def replace_all(text, dict):
    for i, k in dict.iteritems():
        #replace all whole words of I with K in lower cased text, regex = \bSTRING\b
        text = re.sub(r"\b" + i + r"\b", k , text.lower())
    return text
```

The problem is that `re.sub()` doesnt match `u'aren\u2019t'` with `u"aren't"`.

What can I do so that my `replace_all()` function will match both `"hello"` and `"aren't" and replace them with the appropriate text? Can I do something in Python so that my dictionary doesn't contain Unicode? Could I convert my text to use a Unicode character, or could I modify the regex to match the Unicode character as well as all the other text?

Comment: what output would you like to get?

Comment: The expected result is that the text "aren't" is replaced with "ain't".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your problem is:

```
text = u"aren't"
```

instead of:

```
text = u"aren’t"
```

(note the different apostrophes?)

Here's your code modified to make it work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

d = {
    u'aren’t': u'ain’t',
    u'hello': u'hey'
    }
#text = u"aren't"
text = u"aren’t"


def replace_all(text, d):
    for i, k in d.iteritems():
        #replace all whole words of I with K in lower cased text, regex = \bSTRING\b
        text = re.sub(r"\b" + i + r"\b", k , text.lower())
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    newtext = replace_all(text, d)
    print newtext
```

Output:

```
ain’t
```

Comment: Was able to fix my problems which came from the text having different types of apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in Python 2.6.4:

```
>>> re.sub(ur'\baren\u2019t\b', 'rep', u'aren\u2019t')
u'rep'
```

Make sure that your pattern string is a Unicode string, otherwise it might not work.

Answer (score 0):

try saving your file into UTF-8 encode

Answer (score 0):

```
u"aren\u2019t" == u"aren't"
```

False

```
u"aren\u2019t" == u"aren’t"
```

True